# Is there no equivalent of millis() from Arduino in C++?

Tags: c++

I am currently implementing a PID controller for a project I am doing, but I realized I don't know how to ensure a fixed interval for each iteration. I want the PID controller to run at a frequency of 10Hz, but I don't want to use any sleep functions or anything that would otherwise slow down the thread it's running in. I've looked around but I cannot for the life of me find any good topics/functions that simply gives me an accurate measurement of milliseconds. Those that I have found simply uses time_t or clock_t, but time_t only seems to give seconds(?) and clock_t will vary greatly depending on different factors.

Is there any clean and good way to simply see if it's been >= 100 milliseconds since a given point in time in C++? I'm using the Qt5 framework and OpenCV library and the program is running on an ODROID X-2, if that's of any helpful information to anyone.

Thank you for reading, Christian.

Comment: I don't know how accurate it would be on your target platform, but maybe [QTime::currentTime](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtime.html#currentTime) is an option?

Comment: If you have C++ 11 features available, I would go with [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock), though.

Comment: Check if your platform has`gettimeofday` function.

Comment: `sleep` is quite literally what you want. Do the work, figure out how long it took you, sleep until you need to do the work again. Anyway, go with `std::chrono` if you have C++11 available, otherwise you will have to find something platform specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the `ODROID X-2` platform but if it's at all unixy you may have access to `gettimeofday` or `clock_gettime` either one of which would provide a higher resolution clock if available on your hardware.

Comment: clock_gettime worked perfectly, thank you. I didn't try gettimeofday as I found [this](http://blog.habets.pp.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time) article beforehand.